# On an SVN repository, can you ignore all extensions except one?

Tags: svn, svn-server

Our need is to store only axcrypted (.AXX) documents in an SVN repository, and we want to prevent accidental uploading of the non-encrypted documents. Is there a way to do this on SVN server?

We would like to enforce this .AXX only policy on server-side of the SVN, so we don't have to rely on the ignore list of all our SVN clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can do this with a pre-commit hook, an example in Python is [here](http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook).  Instead of checking files for tabs, you could look at their extensions, and return a non-zero exit code if you want to abort the transaction.